# Express/node.js app.use for router makes client lag out

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I wrote up this code on the server side (called app.js):

```
console.log("Server started. If you're reading this then your computer is still alive."); //Unnecessary test command to make sure everything works.

var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var serv = require("http").Server(app);

const router = express.Router;
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client");
});
app.use("/", router);

app.use("/client", express.static(__dirname + "/client"));

serv.listen(2000);

//Set up server stuff. This isn't touched.

var io = require("socket.io")(serv, {});
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("Socket connection"); //This will print to the server, not the developer console in your browser.
});

//Initialize sockets and set up socket listeners. This isn't touched either, except when adding new events.

console.log("Ok"); //Just make sure.
```

And I have a client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Multiplayer!</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script>
        var socket = io();
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I run `node app.js` in the terminal and then go to localhost:2000 on my browser, it takes a minute or two to load, and then says "localhost didn't send any data" (on Chrome). When I comment out `app.use("/", router);`, it loads nicely (it doesn't work, because it can't `GET /`), so I know that there's something wrong with that line, but I don't know what. I looked around the express API documentation but couldn't find anything, so I'm asking here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
const router = express.Router;
app.use("/", router);
```

is just wrong.

If you wanted to actually create a separate router, you would call the `express.Router()` constructor like to actually create a new router and then assign some routes to the new router ([doc and example code here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router)):

```
// call router constructor and then assign some routes to it
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/something, function(req, res) {
    // handle this route here
});
// hook the router into our instance of express
app.use("/", router);
```

---

The crux of the issue is that `express.Router` is a factory function that creates a router.  It's not a router itself.  You have to execute it with `express.Router()` to actually make a router.

The code you had before would not send any response because when it tried to execute `express.Router`, it would call that function expecting it to be middleware.  And, any correctly implemented middleware has to either send a response OR call `next()` to chain to the next middleware/route in the chain.  The `express.Router` factory function does neither of those (it creates a new Router when called and is not the proper type of function to actually be a route handler all by itself) so the request just gets orphaned at that point, never sending anything to the client and never advancing to the other route handlers.

Eventually the request will time out.

Comment: Thanks! I switched my `app.use` for `"/"` out for `router.use`and switched the path a bit. Thanks!